# OS Error while doing requests for images with multiple threads in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests

I'm making a program that gets info from a website about games, among that info, images, since i'm trying to download info of all games on that website, using a single thread with a 1Mbps connection would be very painful, so i decided to take action against this issue and programmed to spawn a thread for each letter of the alphabet that a game starts with, (games can be filtered by such). So, inside the function that downloads the corresponding image to certain game, while i have more than one thread, at some point in execution (sooner or later) an error is raised, then inside the except block that handles it, another exception is raised, and so on, over and over... this immediately causes threads to come to an end, but the fact is that, when i'm left with only a petty single thread to rely on, that thread goes on very well without giving any trouble.

**Question:**
How to solve this, and why is it happening?

**Deduction:**
I think that, when multiple threads get to requests.get line inside the **download_image** function (the function where the very problem must lie), maybe it fails because of multiple requests... that is as far as i can try to guess.

I really **don't have the least idea** of how to solve this, that being said, i would appreciate **any help**, thanks in advance.

*I got rid of all the functions not having to do anything with the problem described above.*
I spawn the threads at program's end, and each thread target function is named **get_all_games_from_letter**.

**CODE**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from string import ascii_lowercase
from datetime import date
from vandal_constants import *
from PIL import Image
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from exceptions import NoTitleException
from validator_collection import url as url_check
from rawgpy import RAWG
from io import BytesIO
import traceback
import requests
import threading
import sqlite3
import concurrent.futures

###  GLOBALS   #####
FROM_RAWG = False
INSERT_SQL = ''
# CONSTANTS ########

rawg = RAWG('A Collector')
#################
def download_image(tag=None, game=None, rawg_game=None):
    if tag:
        return sqlite3.Binary(requests.get(url).content) if (url := tag['data-src']) else None
    elif game:
        global FROM_RAWG
        img_tag = game.select_one(IMG_TAG_SELECTOR)
        if img_tag and img_tag.get('data-src', None):
            try:
                if url_check(img_tag['data-src']):
                    return sqlite3.Binary(requests.get(img_tag['data-src']).content)
                print(f"{img_tag['data-src']} is NOT a valid url")
            except ConnectionError:
                try:
                    print('Error While downloading from "Vandal.elespannol.com" website:')
                    traceback.print_exc()
                except Exception:
                    print('Another Exception Ocurred')
                    traceback.print_exc()
            except OSError:
                print('Error en el Handshake parece')
                traceback.print_exc()
                

        FROM_RAWG = True
        if rawg_game and getattr(rawg_game, 'background_image', None):
            try:
                print('Continue to download from RAWG')
                return sqlite3.Binary(requests.get(rawg_game.background_image).content)
            except ConnectionError:
                print('Error While downloading from RAWG:')
                traceback.print_exc()
            

    return None
def prepare_game_record(game, db_games_set):
    global INSERT_SQL


    title = getattr(game.select_one(TITLE_TAG_SELECTOR), 'text', None)

    if not title:
        raise NoTitleException()

    if title in db_games_set:
        print(f'Already Have {title} in database')
        return None
    
    description = game.select_one(DESCRIPTION_TAG_SELECTOR)
    rawg_game = None
    try:
        rawg_game = rawg.search(title)[0]
    except Exception as err:
        print('No rawg')
        traceback.print_exc()
        
    game_data = {
        'nombre': title,
        'descripcion': description.text if description else rawg_game.description if rawg_game else '',
        'genero': genres if (genres := translate_genres(game.select_one(GENRES_TAG_SELECTOR).contents[1].strip().split(' / '))) else '',
        'fondo':  resize_image(img) if (img := download_image(game=game, rawg_game=rawg_game)) and not FROM_RAWG else img,
        'year': None,
    }

    if not INSERT_SQL:
        INSERT_SQL = construct_sql_insert(**game_data)

    if hasattr(rawg_game, 'released'):
        game_data['year'] = date.fromisoformat(rawg_game.released).year
   

    return tuple(game_data.values())

def get_all_games_from_letter(letter):
    global FROM_RAWG
    counter = 36
    hashes_set = set()

    with sqlite3.connect('/media/l0new0lf/LocalStorage/data.db') as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f'SELECT nombre FROM juegos where nombre like "{letter.upper()}%"')
        db_games_set = []
        for row in cursor:
            db_games_set.append(row[0])
        db_games_set = set(db_games_set)

        while True:
            try:
                prepared_games = []
                rq = requests.get(
                    f'https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/{letter}/inicio/{counter}')

                if rq:
                    print('Request GET: from ' +
                        f'https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/{letter}/inicio/{counter}' + ' Got Workable HTML !')
                else:
                    print('Request GET: from ' +
                        f'https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/{letter}/inicio/{counter}' + ' Not Working !!, getting next page!')
                    continue

                if rq.status_code == 301 or rq.status_code == 302 or rq.status_code == 303 or rq.status_code == 304:
                    print(f'No more games in letter {letter}\n**REDIRECTING TO **')
                    break

                counter += 1

                soup = BeautifulSoup(rq.content, 'lxml')
                main_table = soup.select_one(GAME_SEARCH_RESULTS_TABLE_SELECTOR)

                if hash(main_table.get_text()) not in hashes_set:
                    hashes_set.add(hash(main_table.get_text()))
                else:
                    print('Repeated page ! I\'m done with this letter.')
                    break

                game_tables = main_table.find_all(
                    'table', {'class': GAME_TABLES_CLASS})

                print('entering game_tables loop')

                for game in game_tables:
                    FROM_RAWG = False
                    try:
                        game_record = prepare_game_record(game, db_games_set)
                    except NoTitleException:
                        print('There is no title for this game, DISCARDING!')
                        continue
                    except Exception as err:
                        print('Unknown ERROR in prepare_games_record function')
                        traceback.print_exc()
                        continue
                        


                    if not game_record:
                        continue
                    prepared_games.append(game_record)
                    print('Game successfully prepared !')

                if prepared_games:
                    print(f'Thread, Writing to Database')
                    try:
                        cursor.executemany(INSERT_SQL, prepared_games)
                        connection.commit()

                    except Exception as err:
                        print(err)

                    print('done')

            except Exception as err:
                print('TRULY UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION')
                print(err)
                traceback.print_exc()
                continue
#get_all_games_from_letter('c') You use a single thread?, no trouble at all!!
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(len(ascii_lowercase)) as executor:
    for letter in ascii_lowercase:
        executor.submit(get_all_games_from_letter, letter)
```

**Error Stack Trace:**

**Note**: This is only part of the errors, but the rest is the very same.

```
Game successfully prepared !
Error While downloading from "Vandal.elespannol.com" website:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 366, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 366, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem what one would need is just add a global lock in order that when each thread tries to request.get an image, it has to ask in the first place if some thread is already using it. That is, downloading an image is restricted to just simultaneously one use for all threads

```
#######GLOBALS####
lock = threading.Lock() #Add this to globals variables
##################

def download_image(tag=None, game=None, rawg_game=None):
    if tag:
        return sqlite3.Binary(requests.get(url).content) if (url := tag['data-src']) else None
    elif game:
        global FROM_RAWG
        img_tag = game.select_one(IMG_TAG_SELECTOR)
        if img_tag and img_tag.get('data-src', None):
            try:
                if url_check(img_tag['data-src']):
                    lock.acquire() #acquire the lock for downloading (it means other threads must wait until the one that acquired finishes)
                    temp = sqlite3.Binary(requests.get(img_tag['data-src']).content)
                    lock.release() # release the lock when done with receiving the HttpResponse
                    return temp
                print(f"{img_tag['data-src']} is NOT a valid url")
            except ConnectionError:
                try:
                    print('Error While downloading from "Vandal.elespannol.com" website:')
                    traceback.print_exc()
                except Exception:
                    print('Another Exception Ocurred')
                    traceback.print_exc()
            except OSError:
                print('Error en el Handshake parece')
                traceback.print_exc()
                

        FROM_RAWG = True
        if rawg_game and getattr(rawg_game, 'background_image', None):
            try:
                print('Continue to download from RAWG')
                lock.acquire() #acquire the lock for downloading (it means other threads must wait until the one that acquired finishes)
                temp = sqlite3.Binary(requests.get(rawg_game.background_image).content)
                lock.release() # release the lock when done with
                return temp
            except ConnectionError:
                print('Error While downloading from RAWG:')
                traceback.print_exc()
            

    return None
```

And done, no more troubles with downloading images in multiple threads.... but still... i don't actually know why i would need to make sure of that one request.get is made for all threads, i thought OS handles this issue by using queues or something.